# Bash export: __add_sys_prefix_to_path: not a function

Tags: bash

I 've encuntered a problem. Everytime I open my bash server, it says "-bash: export: __add_sys_prefix_to_path: not a function", which I couldn't find the function on my ~/.bashrc. Can someone help me?

I have tried to search within the bashrc and source it, but it kept return error messagess.Beacuse of the error message, I couldn't export any other paths to bashrc or source it.

Comment: This implies that there's an `export -f` being sourced (and passed as an argument a function name that doesn't exist), but we need enough information to cause this problem on our own system for the question to be answerable.

Comment: A good place to start is `PS4='$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+' bash -xli` to start a new shell with the execution of its dotfiles logged. If that doesn't answer the question on its own, it'll at least give you enough information to ask a narrower question.

Comment: Are you using Mamba? If so, check out the solutions near the bottom of [this thread](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba/issues/1950).

Comment: @Charles Duffy thank you so much, I commented an export -f at the end and it fixed my problem!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a _bash-**server**_, but you have to identify, which line in your setup files causes the error. Most likely, it's a mistyped identifier, or that you forgot to define a function. If the error message does not tell you file and line number, open your bash with `-x` turned on.